# Query Issue - LEFT JOINS where specific col is match to variable

Tags: php, sql

I`m fetching data from sql with left join query, I want to filter the query to be more specific,
In my database i have customers, every customer have a Group, every user have his customers. i guess you understand now what i need.

every user will see only the rows that relate to him. this is my query:

```
SELECT t.*,c.fname,e.DISCODE,e.AREA,e.COLOR
FROM $tbl_name  AS t
LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON t.MCcode = c.MCcode
LEFT JOIN eventcodes AS e ON t.MCcode = e.MCcode AND t.CODE=e.CODE   
ORDER By `id` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

ON customers table i have field named Group, and when user is connected i have his Group name, so how i can filter this query that only where ( for example ) c.Group = '$Group', all the rows are found in $tbl_name, and the other details i`m fetching by joins. 
thanks!

Comment: `wwhere c.group = $user_group`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want only records where c.Group equal a specific value (only members of one group)?

Comment: show only the rows where MCcode ( on customers ) have the $group value on Group Field in DB

Comment: Evey MCcode on customers have a field Group, i want to show only the rows that have on their customers table ( by MCcode field ) the same value of $group on their field Group ( on customers )

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON t.MCcode = c.MCcode and c.Group = '$Group'
```

Comment: It's displaying the rows like there is no filtering